# Fetching feature layer related data from MySQL or a separate DB on map's info window

Tags: mysql, silverlight-4.0, arcgis, arcgis-server

**Situation is:** 
a). *I am having one feature layer which had been plotted on a base map say polygonal features (blocks of land).* 
b). *Related data (owner names of blocks) in a separate database (like MySQL/ Excel file / Oracle).*

**What I need:**
a). *The data from feature layer and from the database can be shown inside the info window popup simultaneously* (e.g. block name from feature layer and block owner's name from separate database).
b). *The functionality of displaying simultaneous data (from feature layer and database) can be achieved through query related records window.* I have seen an example here [Query Related Records](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#QueryRelatedRecords) but unable to get that where the database connection had been made and the datatable or dataset values are fetched from.

Kindly help as I am new to ArcGIS.

**P.S.: I am using ArcGIS for Silverlight 10.1**

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing data in a seperate database, e.g. MySQL, I'm not sure you can use the Query Related Records route as this allows you to retrieve data from the geodatabase storing the published maps data.  You could place additional data into your geodatabase and access it this way.

However, the method I've used is to create a webservice that accesses the seperate database.  When your user selects a feature from your feature layer you can pass an attribute such as an ID or as you mention, a block name, to the webservice that returns the additional data from the seperate database.  If you are using ASP.NET to host your application you could use WCF to provide the connectivity between the Silverlight application and the webservice.  Alternatively, you could create a webservice that returns the data in JSON format: Silverlight can parse this just as well.